# White rectangles on volume control, wifi connection, calendar menus

Tags: windows-10

I recently installed Windows 10 Pro to my PC. There are white borders/rectangles appearing in volume control, wifi connection menu, calendar (opened from taskbar right corner). Here are some screenshots.

[image: Network Settings]

[image: Volume]

I've already tried disabling Keyboard->Enable shortcut underlines. It doesn't work. Is there a way to fix this ?

Comment: Looks like some kind of accessibility thing... something like "highlight focused item".

Comment: So how to fix it?  I can't find anything on settings under "highlight focused item"

Comment: That was just a vague guess to give you a starting point for searching. I don't know what it might actually be called, and I don't currently have access to a Win10 machine. Maybe someone else will know.

Comment: Does it always appear? I notice I can trigger it by `tab`bing to the item. Looks to be a fairly standard keyboard-focus highlight (you'll see similar dashed borders in webpages when you hit tab to navigate to the next link). Narrator (accessibility tool) does a blue border instead, but that one does always appear on the active item.

Comment: This happens about 1/3times when I click on the volume control,wifi,calendar menu...

Answer (score 1):

Uncheck "underline keyboard shortcuts and access keys" in Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Ease of Access Centre\Make the keyboard easier to use.

Credits to amagasakii from the Windows 10 Forums for pointing this out.

Original source: https://www.tenforums.com/customization/58322-how-do-i-remove-white-border.html